# Is it possible to see what date text was added to a web page?

Tags: e-commerce

My basic issue:

I ordered items from a website. They gave no notification email that my items shipped, but the item and order status changed to "shipped". There is no log of ship date, or any other useful information that might let me know when my items will arrive. I would like to find out when the status updated to "shipped" without calling the company.

Question:

Obviously calling the company is the fastest, simplest solution, but not the most fun. I feel like it should be possible to determine when certain text was added to a web page, possibly through the Google Chrome 'Inspect' toolbar, .NET app using API calls, or some other method. Any ideas of how this might be achieved?

Comment: Can you explain yourself a bit more? According to what I understood, you want to notice when other's page (the one from the ecommerce company) is modified and shows the sell status as shipped? Whether is like that, you can implement a web-scrapper in the worst of the scenaries, or consume the ecommerce website API, in the best.

Comment: @RigobertoRamirezCruz Sure, so take this post for example. You just commented. Yes it shows how long ago you commented, but what if it didn't?  If I right-click -> 'Inspect' from Google Chrome, I can select your comment and see the corresponding HTML/CSS code. Is there a way to see the date that your comment text was added to the web page? Retro-actively, I don't care about receiving notification if a page is updated.

Comment: A more concise example is the ecommerce site has an image that say "Processed" and once items ship, it changes to "Shipped". I am looking to find the date that the image changed from the "Processed" image to the "Shipped" image.

Comment: I got it, but according to what I know, that is not possible, well, at least not in an elegant solution. I don't think HTML elements have a timestamp unless the programmer has printed it.